# Vue.js Webpack: how to return an an asset path from :src binded to to a method

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuetify.js

In my component template , I have :

```
 <v-avatar :tile="tile" color="grey lighten-4" class="layout justify-start ml-0" slot="activator" size="48px">
   <img class="img-circle" :src="avatarUrl" alt="avatar">
 </v-avatar>
```

the src tag is bound to the avatarUrl method

```
  methods: {
    avatarUrl () {
      if (this.user.photoUrl !== null) {
        return this.user.photoUrl
      } else {
        return 'https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/9064066?v=4&s=46
      }
    },
```

this works well... BUT if I want to use an image from the src/assets/images then the image is not used . ( no error messagecompiling or executing )

```
  methods: {
    avatarUrl () {
      if (this.user.photoUrl !== null) {
        return this.user.photoUrl
      } else {
        return '../../assets/images/default-avatar.jpeg'
      }
    },
```

I also tried to use require()

```
return require('../../assets/images/default-avatar.jpeg')
```

UPDATE

I this case I get an error

This relative module was not found:

```
* ../../assets/images/default-avatar.jpeg in ./node_modules/cache
loader/dist/cjs.js?"cacheDirectory":"/Users/myself/Developments/my-
 project/node_modules/.cache/cacheloader"}!./node_modules/babel
loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js
type=script&index=0!./src/components/Member/Section1.vue
```

I guess that during compilation webpack only checks urls in the template ? what about the script ??

thanks for feedback

Comment: Have you checked [this article](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html)?

Comment: yes, that's why I also tested :  return require('../../assets/images/default-avatar.jpeg'

Comment: did you try to use a computed property instead of a method (using require)?

Comment: yes .. same error message during compilation

Comment: If I use another image ( already used in the template .. i.e. require('../../assets/images/logo.png') then I don't get error as this images is alreday in the cache ..

Comment: After clearing cache and reloading ..... then the avayar image appears !! miracle of the caches ... thanks for feedback . write your answer as a response please .. you help ...

Comment: does it work using a method? or computed property? In my case it works only with a computed property

Comment: yes... computed property only